# Document.documentElement.scrollTop in IE8 activated at wrong height

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, scroll

**Problem**

I have an element which becomes fixed when the user scrolls past it, so it follows the user down the page.

I've been trying to make it IE8 compatible and running into problems.

`$(window).scrollTop()` has problems in IE8 so I've been trying to offer a second option for IE8: `document.documentElement.scrollTop`

This turns my code would be:

```
if ($(window).scrollTop() || (document.documentElement.scrollTop) > 90) {
    //if scroll top goes past fixed header add class
    $(scrollbox).addClass('affix');
 }
else {
    $(scrollbox).removeClass('affix');
 }
```

While this makes it scroll correctly in IE8, it now begins to scroll immediately in Chrome and Firefox.

I tried offsetting it so it would scroll later, however this doesn't do anything:

```
(document.documentElement.scrollTop - 100)
```

The class is still attached as soon as you begin scrolling.

As a last resort I can add an IE8 specific style and make the jquery conditional on that, however I would prefer to understand whats going wrong. Can anyone help?

Comment: If you're using an older version of jQuery (pre 1.7) you can use something like `if ($.browser.msie && $.browser.version == 8) /* do IE specific */` OR, if you're on a newer one, I made a plugin that would allow `if ($.browser.browser == "MSIE" && $.browser.version == 8) /*|OR| traditional*/ if ($.browser.msie && $.browser.version == 8)` ***Plugin:*** http://jsfiddle.net/SpYk3/7eSmd/10/

Comment: Keep in mind, the plugin is meant to work with later versions of jQuery and I don't think it supports less than IE 6, or I haven't been able to test it on anything that low at least.

Comment: Because I have to have conditional IE8 stylesheets anyway I check for a style only in the IE8 sheet, with an ID selector. But as I said I was hoping to solve without conditionals if I can avoid it.

Comment: As long as you have to support anything IE, you will have to support conditionals. And as far as CSS goes, Mozilla is starting to become the same way. Just a word of caution, careful how you use CSS2.1 relevant chain selectors as Firefox will crash if not done the way Mozilla wants. Just a little something extra for ya not a lot sem to know yet.